# Strange result in routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have the following set up in my route file

```
Route::resource('reports', 'CampaignReport\CampaignReportController');
Route::get('reports/generateExcel', array('as' => 'reports.generateExcel', 'uses' => 'CampaignReport\CampaignReportController@generateExcel'));
```

I am not tieing it to a Model as it is just for creating generic reports.  If I output my routes I see (I have removed some of the common ones)

```
|        | GET|HEAD                       | reports                                                                              | reports.index                                     | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignReport\CampaignReportController@index           | auth
|        | GET|HEAD                       | reports/create                                                                       | reports.create                                    | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignReport\CampaignReportController@create          | auth
|        | GET|HEAD                       | reports/generateExcel                                                                | reports.generateExcel                             | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignReport\CampaignReportController@generateExcel   | auth
|        | GET|HEAD                       | reports/{reports}                                                                    | reports.show                                      | App\Http\Controllers\CampaignReport\CampaignReportController@show            | auth
```

So everything looks fine.  Now in one of my views, I have the following

```
<td>{!! link_to_route('reports.generateExcel', 'Generate Excel', null, array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}</td>
```

So that should trigger the generateExcel function within my controller.  At the moment, my controller is like so

```
public function show()
{
    return "SHOW PAGE";
}

public function generateExcel()
{
    return "EXCEL GENERATED";
}
```

Now the strange thing is, that link to route returns SHOW PAGE for some reason, when it should return EXCEL GENERATED.  However, if I make a change in my route and remove the show route e.g.

```
Route::resource('reports', 'CampaignReport\CampaignReportController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

The same link to route will now show what it is supposed too and that is EXCEL GENERATED.

So why would the show function be called in the first instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `reports/generateExcel` matches the pattern for the `show` route `reports/{reports}`. If you changed your controller to display the value of `{reports}`, e.g.

```
public function show($id)
{
    return "SHOW PAGE for '$id'";
}
```

then you'd see `SHOW PAGE for 'generateExcel'` in the output.

The solution is to simply register your custom route *before* the `Route::resource()`, as per the docs:

> **Supplementing Resource Controllers**
>
> If it becomes necessary to add additional routes to a resource
>   controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those
>   routes before your call to `Route::resource`; otherwise, the routes
>   defined by the `resource` method may unintentionally take precedence
>   over your supplemental routes

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers